# Message queue in Perl

Tags: c, perl, ipc, message-queue

I want to implement a message queue with Perl. I get data from stdin and send it to the queue.

My message's structure is

```perl
struct message => {
    mtype        => '$',
    buffer_size  => '$',
    last_message => '$',
    buff         => '$',
};
```

I have to receive data from the queue with a C program. My C program works well before, but now when I run it to receive data from queue it shows me something like this

```
age=HASH(0x1daa088) 1936942445      4000
```

I read chunks of data with a 4000-byte buffer that I print on stdout. But instead of `age=HASH(0x1daa088)   1936942445` the program should print the size of message received.

What happened here? Is it because the message in C is a structure and in Perl it's a hash?

My C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/ipc.h>
#include <linux/msg.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define bufsize 4000

struct mymsgbuf {
    long    mtype;          /* Message type */
    int     buffer_size;
    char    buff[bufsize];
    int     last_message;
} msg;

int read_message( int qid, long type, struct mymsgbuf *qbuf ) {

    int result, length;

    /* The length is essentially the size of the structure minus   sizeof(mtype)*/

    length = sizeof(struct mymsgbuf) - sizeof(long);

    if ( (result = msgrcv( qid, qbuf, length, type, MSG_NOERROR)) == -1 ) {
        return(-1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d  \n", qbuf->buffer_size, bufsize, qbuf->last_message);

    write(1,qbuf->buff,qbuf->buffer_size);

    return(result);
}

int open_queue( key_t keyval ) {

    int qid;

    if ( (qid = msgget( keyval, 0660 )) == -1 ) {
        return(-1);
    }

    return(qid);
}

main() {

    int     qid;
    key_t   msgkey;
    msg.last_message = 0;

    /* Generate our IPC key value */
    msgkey = ftok("/home/joobeen/Desktop/learning", 'm');

    /* Open/create the queue */
    if (( qid = open_queue( msgkey)) == -1) {
        perror("open_queue");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "byte received:\tbuffer_size:\tlast_message:\n");

    /* Bombs away! */
    while (1) {

        if ( (read_message( qid,0, &msg )) == -1 ) {
            perror("receive_message");
            exit(1);
        }
        if ( msg.last_message == 1 )
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My Perl code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::SysV qw(IPC_PRIVATE IPC_CREAT S_IRUSR S_IWUSR ftok);
use IPC::Msg;
use Class::Struct;

struct message => {
    mtype        => '$',
    buffer_size  => '$',
    last_message => '$',
    buff         => '$',
};

my $key_in = ftok( "/home/joobeen/Desktop/learning", 'm' );
my ( $buffer ) = "";
my $buf_size   = 4000;
my $file       = shift @ARGV;
my $ifh;
my $is_stdin  = 0;
my $type_sent = 1;
my $last;

if ( defined $file ) {
    open $ifh, "<", $file or die $!;
}
else {
    $ifh = *STDIN;
    $is_stdin++;
}

my $ipc_id = msgget( $key_in, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
my $msg = message->new(
    mtype        => 1,
    last_message => 0
);

print "\tbyte sent\tbuffer_size\tlast_message\n";

while ( <$ifh> ) {

    $last = read( $ifh, $buffer, $buf_size );

    $msg->buff( $buffer );
    $msg->buffer_size( $buf_size );

    if ( $last < $buf_size ) {
        $msg->last_message( 1 );
    }

    msgsnd( $ipc_id, pack( "l! a*", $type_sent, $msg ), 0 );

    print "\t", $last, "\t\t", $buf_size, "\t\t", $msg->last_message, "\n";

}

close $ifh unless $is_stdin;
```

Comment: Please show your Perl and C code; we can't tell very much without it. What Perl module are you using to provide the `struct` keyword? Is it [Class::Struct](http://metacpan.org/module/Class::Struct)?

Comment: @Borodin i use class::struct.edit my question and now u can see my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems. I won't fix them all for you but I can give you some guideline on how to implement IPC in general.

Reading binary data directly into C structs is extremely fragile. You have to care about byte order, struct padding and the size of types like `int` or `long`. Depending on your platform, both of these types could be 32-bit or 64-bit and little or big endian. So first of all, you need an exact specification of the "on-the-wire protocol" of your messages. To simplify things, let's use fixed-sized messages:

```
mtype: 32-bit unsigned integer, little endian
buffer_size: 32-bit unsigned integer, little endian
buffer: 4000 bytes
last_message: 32-bit unsigned integer, little endian
```

This is just an example. You could use big endian integers as well, like most network protocols do for historical reasons. If you only want to use IPC on a single machine, you could also specify native byte order.

Now the length of a message is fixed to 4012 bytes. To decode such a message in a portable way in C, you should read it into a `char` array and extract each field separately. You know each field's offset and size.

Encoding such a message in Perl is easy using the [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) function:

```perl
my $msg = pack('V V a4000 V', $mtype, $buffer_size, $buffer, $last);
```

There's no need for `Class::Struct`. This module does not do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your usefull answer.i do what u said and change my c and perl code.i send my msg like this  msgsnd($ipc_id,pack('V V a4000 V', $type_sent, $buf_size, $buffer, $last_message), 0); can u tell me its true or not pls?